# I have 3 directories called dir1, dir2, dir3. Now I need to create home and hostel directories in all the 3 directories in one command

Tags: linux-headers

Is this possible to create multiple/single directories in Multiple directories in one command?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? What kind of course is this?

Comment: Yes you can give `mkdir` multiple directory arguments where the same option(s) will be applied to all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mkdir -p {dir1,dir2,dir3}/{home,hostel}
$ ls */*
dir1/home:
dir1/hostel:
dir2/home:
dir2/hostel:
dir3/home:  
dir3/hostel:
```

Comment: Thank you so much